# Failed to load map using google map android api v2

Tags: android, google-maps, xamarin

**I got this following error when loading google map android api v2**

```
1. Authorization failure.
2. Ensure that the following correspond to what is in the API Console: Package Name: com.example, API Key: AIzaSyDjm0K-ucpO5mDCPPnQ4CzVpdguqM714uo, Certificate Fingerprint: D9595FF0F329A6BBAC466C63284F83D17859894B
3. Failed to contact Google servers. Another attempt will be made when connectivity is established.
4. Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers. This is probably an authentication issue (but could be due to network errors).
5. Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.gsf.gservices
```

**Here's my source code:**

**My AndroidManifest source code**

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"   android:installLocation="auto" package="com.example">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="14" />

    <application android:label="map" android:icon="@drawable/Icon">
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="AIzaSyDjm0K-ucpO5mDCPPnQ4CzVpdguqM714uo" />
    </application>

    <permission android:name="com.example.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
</manifest>
```

**My Main.axml source code**

**Main.axml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
```

**My Activity1 source code**

**Activity1.cs**

```
using System;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;

namespace map
{
    [Activity(Label = "map", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class Activity1 : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        }
     }
}
```

By the way I'am using API Level 15 emulator.

**Here's my api key**

[image]

Comment: why is this tagged C#?

Comment: where is the error message?

Comment: post the error message and also your layout, and we could help you with this.

Comment: I'am using c# not java

Comment: I already posted my errors at the top of this post. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the answer to my problem. My SHA1 fingerprint doesnt match the certificate fingerprint I use ( in my error message). Now my application loads the android google map properly.

Comment: How did you verify your SHA1 fingerprint doesnt match.

Answer (score 1):

Although it is not recommended, it is possible to setup the emulator to support the Android Maps API v2. The emulator must be configured to target the **Google API Level 17** (Android 4.2.2) or higher. 

Yours is set to **API Level 15**...

Also you need to set your project's target API and min API Level to 17 (it is currently 14) if you want to load Google map  in Emulator.

Read the prerequisites here:
http://docs.xamarin.com/Guides/Android/Platform_Features/Maps_and_Location/Part_2_-_Maps_API/#Configuring_Maps_API_Prerequisites

Comment: To add to this, only the AVD for the most recent API is supported. So, an AVD using API level 17 or 18 probably has an out of date version of Google Play Services that might not work to well with your application.

Comment: I'am using real device in debugging but still map doesn't load. It only displays white screen with google logo and zoom in and out icon.

Answer (score 0):

Write the following feature to your menifest

```
<uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />
```

Comment: check that you are enabled the correct Google map API service for android, which is Google Maps Android API v2.

Comment: In my emulator it only display's white background with google logo and zoom in and out button.

Comment: I doubled check it. I am using Google Maps Android V2

Comment: I also checked my API key in androidmanifest and api console its just the same.

Answer (score 0):

Improve your xml

```
 <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.**SupportMapFragment**" />
```

Comment: I' am targeting API Level 15 and up, SupportMapFragment will not work here.

Comment: ok then  make a new google console key nd try it.
 i think there is the problem with your key

Comment: Link to create an api key..:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start?hl=zh-CN



Also you can take you SHAI from your eclipse too

Comment: I have tried it so many times but still I'am getting same same problem again and again.